# Can't remove environmental variable in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java, environment-variables

I have set my environmental variable `$JAVA_HOME` within the `/etc/environment` file.  Worked like a charm!  Now I want to remove it.  After removing the line completely from the environment file, then do a reboot, it continues to resolve the path on:

echo $JAVA_HOME

How do I clean that out?

Comment: Although I posted an answer on how to unset a variable, it appears you might be setting `$JAVA_HOME` in more than one place. What does it read when you type `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$JAVA_HOME` will already have a definition on many systems without explicitly declaring it in `/etc/environment`:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

That said, the `unset` command will eliminate a variable. From: [Unix / Linux - Using Shell Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm)

> ### Unsetting Variables
>
> Unsetting or deleting a variable directs the shell to remove the
>   variable from the list of variables that it tracks. Once you unset a
>   variable, you cannot access the stored value in the variable.
>
> Following is the syntax to unset a defined variable using the unset
>   command −
>
> ```
> unset variable_name
> ```
>
> The above command unsets the value of a defined variable. Here is a
>   simple example that demonstrates how the command works −
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> NAME="Zara Ali"
> unset NAME
> echo $NAME
> ```

In our case we can use:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ unset JAVA_HOME
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ echo $JAVA_HOME

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$
```